# Meaning of ^ in flex

Tags: compilation, compiler-construction, flex-lexer, lexical-analysis

I have got a question about flex. In my notes, in a sample code fragment it says the following:

```
[^ \t\n]+ printf("saw a word\n");
```

I do not understand what that code means, and how it corresponds to a word. It looks like `\t` means when we see a blank, and `\n` means when we see the newline character, but what is the meaning of `^` at the beginning, and what exactly `[^ \t\n]+` means? I would appreciate if somebody can explain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[]` is a character group and matches all characters specified in it. `^` in that context inverts the whole thing, and the character group matches everything **but** the characters specified. So in this case, it matches everything but a space, tab or newline character.

Comment: but, in this case, let us assume this is the only rule and the input is "hello". Does it print out "Saw a word" 5 times? Because when it sees h, it prints since it is not a newline, tab or blank, and then for e, ... etc. In this case we are not actually printing when we see a word, right?

Comment: @bigO No, it prints once, because of greediness. It matches the longest string possible.